# External CSS file not working like embedded for UL?

Tags: css

I can't figure it out still. I managed to use an image as a bullet for an unordered list and it works only if the css code is inside the html file where I have the UL (doesn't matter if I attach an ID to the list or class). This is my snippet:

```
<head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="fis_css/subtitles.css" type="text/css" name="stil_b">



    <style type="text/css">

      .lista{
             list-style-image:url("buttons/pic.gif");
             background-repeat:no-repeat;
             }

    </style>

    </head>


<body>

<div id="lista_meniu">
   <ul class="lista">
      <li><a href="#c1">Perioadele critice de dezvoltare al creierului la copii </a></li> 
      <hr>
      <li><a href="#c2">Dezvoltarea vizual&#259; &#351;i auditiv&#259; </a></li>
      <hr>    
      <li><a href="#c3">Dezvoltarea limbajului verbal </a></li> 
      <hr>   
      <li><a href="#c4">Dezvoltarea fizic&#259; &#351;i motorie </a></li> 
      <hr>   
      <li><a href="#c5">Dezvoltarea emo&#355;ional&#259; &#351;i social&#259; </a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

....................................
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you are using for the image is correct when relative to the html file, but not the css.

Assuming your image folder and css folder are on the same level, you may need to add `../` to the beginning of the image url.

So the url you use is right when you use it inside the html page, but as your css is in a lower directory, it will not be able to find the same image using the same relative url.

Comment: No, the path is relative to the style sheet. See my answer.

Comment: I meant the one he is using, not how it actually works. I'll clarify my answer.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the relative URL specified for the image is relative to the external CSS location, not relative to your document

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url

Specify an absolute URL to the `li` image.